# jquery load get variables back from loaded php file

Tags: jquery, load

i'm loading a php file with jquery .load.

with load it just loads my php file and displays it into my tabs which works fine.

but know i wanna pass some variable from the loaded file into the mainfile back.

how can i solve this ?

thanks a lot for you help

Comment: can you post some of your code, so someone can suggest accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#feeds").load("feeds.php", {limit: 25}, function(){
alert("The last 25 entries in the feed have been loaded");
});
```

whereas limit is your name and 25 the value of the parameter

see: [the API](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more information on this

Comment: Thanks, but i don't wann's send Data to the php file which is loaded with .load. I wanna receive Data. Example. I have a php file Index.php. This Index.php file load  comments.php over jquery .load. What Works fine is that the comments are displayed in the Index file. What i need is to get the values of a variable from comments.php in the Index.php. How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of would be to to have some hidden field containing the data you want in the page getting loaded. You could then simply get the values using jQuery after the load event.